# Push button for QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4, qtgui, qpushbutton

I would like add QPushButtons to my QTableView. How can this be done with Qt? Is it possible to specify which column holds the button If I use QItemDelegate?

Answer (score 2):

You've got to create your own PushButtonDelegate by subclassing `QItemDelegate`.

`QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn(int column, QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate)` will set your delegate for the specified column of a view.

The implementation of the delegate depends on it's desired behavior. E.g. you can implement only `createEditor()`, `setEditorData()` and `setModelData()` to get the button to appear when the user starts editing a cell, or you can change the cell look completely by reimplementing the delegate's `paint()` method.
For more information see [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes). Also take a look at the Qt delegate examples.